# Не срабатывает привязка Xamarin.Form + Prism

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

Всем привет сталкиваюсь впервые с такой проблемой до этого было всё отлично. Использую Xamarin.Forms + Prism дело в том что не срабатывает привязка что очень странно вроде все сделал как нужно. Помогите пожалуйста заранее спасибо!

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="BlankApp1.Views.MainPage"
         xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
         Title="{Binding Title}">
<StackLayout>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding List}" SeparatorVisibility="Default" BackgroundColor="Black" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Path=Id}"  Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"  Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Path=BeginTime}"  Grid.Column="3"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Path=EndTime}"  Grid.Column="4"/>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Модель

```
 public class Worker : BindableBase
{
    private string _id;
    private string _firstname;
    private string _lastName;
    private string _begindTime;
    private string _endTime;

    private string _nameApp;
    public string NameApp { get => _nameApp; set => SetProperty(ref _nameApp, value); }
    public string Id { get => _id; set => SetProperty(ref _id, value); }
    public string FirstName { get => _firstname; set => SetProperty(ref _firstname, value); }
    public string LastName { get => _lastName; set => SetProperty(ref _lastName, value); }
    public string BeginTime { get => _begindTime; set => SetProperty(ref _begindTime, value); }
    public string EndTime { get => _endTime; set => SetProperty(ref _endTime, value); }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Worker> List = new ObservableCollection<Worker>()
        {
            new Worker { Id = "Id", FirstName = "FisrtName", LastName = "LastName", BeginTime = "BeginTime", EndTime = "EndTime" },
            new Worker { Id = "Id", FirstName = "FisrtName", LastName = "LastName", BeginTime = "BeginTime", EndTime = "EndTime" },
            new Worker { Id = "Id", FirstName = "FisrtName", LastName = "LastName", BeginTime = "BeginTime", EndTime = "EndTime" }
        };

    public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService): base(navigationService)
    {
        Title = "Main Page";
    }
}
```

ViewModelBase

```
 public class ViewModelBase : BindableBase, IInitialize, INavigationAware, IDestructible
{
    protected INavigationService NavigationService { get; private set; }

    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
    }

    public ViewModelBase(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        NavigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public virtual void Initialize(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {

    }

    public virtual void OnNavigatedFrom(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {

    }

    public virtual void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {

    }

    public virtual void Destroy()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь использовать MVVM фреймворк без понимания, как работают привязки данных. Это ни к чему хорошему не приведет и не поможет вам написать приложение, а скорее помешает. Попробуйте реализовать для начала то же самое, только без Prism. Реализуете INPC `public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged` - и так далее в том же духе.

Comment: Привязка идет к **публичный свойствам**.

Comment: @aepot если вы утверждаете что у меня нет никакого понимания укажите мне пожалуйсста на мою ошибку в коде. Я просто для себя хочу понять может я правда что то не понимаю или что то упустил.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ А у меня повашему мнению к закрытым свойствам идет привязка?

Comment: Хм, по моему мнению у вас вообще нету свойства для привязки) `public ObservableCollection<Worker> List = new ObservableCollection<Worker>()`

Comment: _если вы утверждаете что у меня нет никакого понимания_ - я этого не утверждал, я дал совет как понять принципы работы привязок. _укажите мне пожалуйсста на мою ошибку в коде_ - как пожелаете `public ObservableCollection<Worker> List { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Worker>()`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Всё отлично у меня вы зря наговариваете. Посмотрите что такое [Prism](https://prismlibrary.com/) и вы поймёте как всё работает!

Comment: @aepot `public ObservableCollection<Worker> List { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Worker>()` это всего лишь авто свойство и ничего более. к привязки смысла не имеет. Я просто этот код быстро набросал чтоб посмотреть что правда ли не работает то что я хочу реализовать в своём основном проекте. Но в любом случае на данный момент всё заработало незнаю даже почему. Я просто обновил Xamarin.Forms. Спасибо за советы!

Comment: `авто свойство` - а у вас поле в коде, опубликованном вами выше в вопросе. А привязка к полю невозможна, возможна только к свойству, любому, авто или не авто, не важно. Быть может вы `=` на `=>` поменяли, поэтому заработало, я не могу телепатически отслеживать изменения в вашем коде.

Comment: Я прекрасно знаю, что такое Prism и прекрасно знаю, как он работает, а еще я знаю, что привязка WPF/UWP/Xamarin **невозможна** к **полям**, а у вас тот код, что в вопросе, `List`, является [полем](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zlER.png) и к такому привязка ну попросту невозможна. Не, ну вы можете мне не верить конечно, "работает же", ну а че... Так что пожалуйста, не несите ерунду.